# vue Dynamic Slot Names Error Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vuejs(2.6.11) Dynamic Slot Names Eerror: Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as , as they will not be parsed.

Why Error?

Here is my code:

LightBox.vue file

```
<template>
  <div>
    <header>
      <slot name="header">Default Header</slot>
    </header>
    <hr />
    <main>
      <slot>Default Body</slot>
    </main>
    <hr />
    <footer>
      <slot name="footer">Default Footer</slot>
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

App.vue file

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <label v-for="(opt, index) in options" :key="index">
      <input type="radio" :value="opt" v-model="dynamic_slot_name" /> {{ opt }}
    </label>

    <br><br><hr>

    <light-box>
      <template v-slot:[dynamic_slot_name]>
        <h2>Hello Kieey</h2>
      </template>
    </light-box>
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import LightBox from "./components/LightBox.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    LightBox,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      options: ["header", "footer", "default"],
      dynamic_slot_name: "header",
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

[Error code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-dynamic-slot-names-bokff?file=/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why, but the template parser is having trouble parsing the dynamic slot syntax `v-slot:[dynamic_slot_name]`. Try this instead:

```html
<template v-slot:[dynamic_slot_name]="">
```

Comment: Yep, definitely looks like Vue 2 template compiler bug. Works without any change in Vue 3...